# Managing database connections in multi-threaded socket server

Tags: java, database, multithreading

I have a simple udp server that accepts packets, decodes the packets and inserts them into the database. Since there can be 100,000 concurrent connections, each with time-sensitive data, the data needs to be inserted into the database as quickly as possible.

In order to acheive this, I use a ExecutorService with 50 threads. When packet comes in, one of the threads in pool is used to process the data:

// UdpServer

```
public void run() {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50);        

    while (listening) {
        try {
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];

            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            socket.receive(packet);

            executor.execute(new Responder(socket, packet));                
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       
}
```

Since I have a thread pool, I figured I didn't need a database pool, because at start up each thread can open a database connection. So this is what I did for each Responder thread:

// Responder class

```
public void run() {         
    this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
    processPacket();
    connection.close();
}

private void processPacket(){
    Report report = ReportParser.readReport(packet);
    report.setConnection(connection);
    report.save();
}
```

// Report class

```
public void save(){
    stmt = connection.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(...);
}
```

The problem is it seems when the program starts, it doesn't immediately establish the database connections for each thread. When the packet is sent to server, there is several seconds delay before data is inserted, and this is only one packet. Imagine 100,000.

Would I be better off using a a database pool (like BoneCP) in combination with the thread pool, or would the database pool not aid performance in this situation?

Comment: If you have each Thread read a table at start-up, then the connection will be established.  I would personal prefer to go for a third-party DB Connection pool though.  E.g. Apache DBCP

Comment: You're going to get better throughput if you batch the database writes instead of doing UPDATEs for each one.  I'd have a separate set of threads reading queued events and writing small batches (50 maybe) to the database.  This will let you tune writes like you've done with your inbound data. If the batch is too big, your latency will go up though. And I would suggest a connection pool to help manage the connections.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am using Java 8. Apache DBCP doesn't seem to have support for it. I brought up BoneCP because it was mentioned before on stackoverflow.

Comment: I wonder if DBCP2 is forwardly compatible?  if not BoneCP should do the trick although I have no experience with it.

Comment: @Joshua Martell I am messing around with the Producer-Consumer multithreading technique using ArrayBlockingQueue. I have a producer that decodes packets, and puts the data in the queue and then I have a Consumer which sleeps for 100 milliseconds and then reads the queue. Takes the data from the queue and inserts it into the database. Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable. You might want to do 100ms or say 1000 messages, which ever comes first. Nothing will wait too long, and if things are busy, it'll try to empty the queue sooner. You might look into Redis for a backend, too if you need more performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread pools and database pools have their own purpose. I don't think one can replace the other. Using a database pool, you can rely on them to provide your threads an existing db connection. So IMPO i would go with a database pool along with your DB push thread pool.

Comment: if I use a third party DB connection pool, since I am using 50 threads with ExecuterService, would you recommend to set the DB connection pool to 50 connections to accomodate the 50 threads?

Comment: @JohnMerlino That depends on your DB, if your DB can handle 50 connections without any performance bottleneck, go ahead and do it. But there would not be any point of setting more connections what DB can handle.